# Forwarding request Spring RestController

Tags: spring, rest, spring-boot, spring-restcontroller

I have a Spring REST controller:

```
@RestController
@RequestMapping("v1/employee")
public class controller1 {
 getMethod(@PathVariable String param1, String param2){}
 postMethod(){}
}
```

I want to introduce a new endpoint version `v2` that resolves the params: param1,param2 and forward to the `v1` request urls.

I want the new clients to be able to call `v2` while the old clients are still able to call `v1` endpoints. I looked at Interceptors and Filters. So I should either,

1. forward the requests to v1 or,
2. call controller methods internally

Is there a better way to do this? Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It really depends on the nature of your application

first of all, controllers are supposed to only encapsulate HTTP related stuff, so probably the business logic is implemented in Services.

If so, then there is no need to redirect the request if you're talking about the same java application, it's better just to inject the service to the new controller and call it.

```
class OldController {
   MyService srv;

   @GetMapping(...)
   public oldGet() {
       srv.doSomething();
   }
}

class NewController {
   MyService srv;

   @GetMapping(...)
   public newGet() {
       srv.doSomething();
       //or 
       srv.doSomethingElse(); 
   }
}
```

Now as for the routing, you can even do it externally (like in some kind of proxy that does url rewriting for you and redirects to the correct controller that can even reside on the different server.
Solutions for these are:

- NGNIX
- Zuul
- HA-Proxy

there are others

Comment: I want to avoid rewriting controllers, rather I want to intercept the requests coming to the new API v2, attach param1, param2 and send them to the existing controller v1. is there a way to do that?

Comment: Controller is just a bean, so you can inject it into new controller and call directly, however this is not a usual setup, usually people try to do this declaratively, by using proxy like Zuul, in zuul (different microservice) you can add any arbitrary logic written in Java to "enrich" the original request), other solutions can also to this but provide less programming capabilities in code, and more about external configurations

Comment: yes, but still I will have to define URL mappings for every method right? say there are 5 methods in the v1 controller, so we need to write v2 versions for those 5 methods either way?

Comment: If you know that the request has to be enriched in the same way, you can do it declaratively (like adding header, parameter). Usually requests are read only, so you'll have to use HttpRequestWrapper for this,

Comment: However, its not like this for path. When request arrives, its already "intended" to be run by controller already (the old controller), so you can change the target controller by altering the request path which should be done before the request arrives to your application (which is in other words some kind of proxy capable of altering the request context path, its also called url rewritting)